# How can I get the boot time of a laptop from the event log with C#?

Tags: c#, events, wmi

Not sure if this is something captured by the WMI, or whether it can be derived from the event log, but I want to be able to report on laptop boot time (e.g. from power on, to usable) in a similar manner to Soluto.

Doesn't need to be as complex as that though - Soluto shows when various services start / become ready etc - I just want to know how long a laptop took to boot from the user entering their credentials to the laptop becoming ready to use.

This article shows how to get the value from the event log manually. How can I get this with C#?

http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-20101652-285/find-your-computers-boot-time-in-windows-7/

Comment: So your question is how can I connect to Windows Event logs using C#?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show us your code.

Comment: Not tried anything -  no idea where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a place to start:

The `Diagnostics-Performance` log is what the article says you need.  This will loop through all the events in that log if it exists on your machine.

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();    
eventLog1.Log = "Diagnostics-Performance";
foreach (System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry entry in eventLog1.Entries)
{
    Console.WriteLine(entry.Message);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - will look around in this. (Can code OK in C# but mainly do web stuff. Never tried interacting with the Event Viewer so this pointer is much appreciated!)